# Is there a standard for mobile display connectors?

Tags: connector, pins, display

I want to build something using displays from old mobile phones, but I don't know how to search for some experimental connector/adapter that "magnifies" those small printed flexible pins to some breadboard like stuff (if such a thing even exists).

Is there a standard for these small printed flexible connectors regarding spacing and pin width?

I'm thinking of connectors like this:

[image]

If there is, what is its name, as well as the name of the corresponding male connector (guessing that it's just the male version of the standard)?

Comment: Both "a link for some development kit that "magnifies" the pins as described above" and "a comprehensive guide to microelectronic connectors would suffice as well." are off-topic. The first one because it's a shopping question and the second one because it's too broad. However, asking for the name of the connector is okay.

Comment: Before you buy an adapter or connector, it is more important to figure out how to communicate with the display, because if you don't know that, you really have no use for adapters or connectors.

Comment: @Justme true...

Comment: @Justme I guarantee you, the display uses the MIPI-DSI protocol. However, it requires some >300MHz signals that are hard to generate. Basically the only thing you can sensibly connect it to, is a GPU or SoC with a MIPI-DSI interface. It's not like VGA where you can make an interesting signal with a handful of 555s

Comment: @user253751 Yes it might use DSI and even if we assume it uses DSI and we can generate a DSI interface with a SoC, we still would not know how to connect the data pins together, how to power the display with some voltage it requires, and the final issue is to generate the video in a suitable resolution and frame rate for it. Too many unknown variables, unless the display type is known and datasheet for it is found.

Answer (score 1):

The tail of that FPC (Flexible Printed Circuit) may be designed for insertion in an [FFC socket](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NNK&n=ffc_fpc_sockets) (my site) which you can buy [here](https://www.digikey.ee/en/products/filter/ffc-fpc-flat-flexible-connectors/ffc-fpc-flat-flexible-connector-assemblies/399) (DigiKey).

[image: Slider FFC socket]

To select an FFC socket, you need:

1. the exact [pitch](https://www.google.com/search?q=connector+pitch) (Hint: measure the center-to-center distance between the first and last contact, and divide by 13)
2. the orientation: straight or right angle
3. If right-angle, whether the contacts should be on the top or the bottom

Answer (score 0):

So the male connector (the cable) is called FFC, which stands for "flexible flat cable", the female connector is called FPC, which stands for "flexible printed circuit".

These types of connectors come in a variety of spacing (pitch), and pin width (also referred to as pitch).

Comment: This is not entirely correct. The connector is called an "FPC connector" or "FFC connector"; the cable is called either an "FPC" or an "FFC". The terms are interchangeable here, though FPC can also refer to something with more than just wires on it.